# Laravel only use cookies for Nova back end

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

We have a Laravel project where cookies on the public need to be disabled for CSRF reasons and the 419 error. However when we comment out the following lines the project works as intended but the Nova admin just throws a 500:

```
  protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
           // \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
           // \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
           // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
           // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
           // \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
           // \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
    ];
```

Is anyone aware of a way of keeping cookies only for nova sessions please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wouldn't disabling cookies make you more susceptible to CSRF rather than less?

Comment: the front end of the site is often embedded, only in nova is the use of any cookie required.

Comment: Ok i'll first point out that you haven't actually disabled cookies here, you've only disabled cookie encryption and the session cookie (all other cookies would still work as normal). Try uncommenting `EncryptCookies` for starters and clearing all your cookies as well. You can always run the `StartSession` middleware on specific routes if you choose to that will read the session cookie (if sent) and then send it back with the response (or set a new one if one was not sent). Then the browser will keep sending it whenever it's set (regardless of your server settings)